# Apache debug message "net/instaweb/apache/instaweb_handler.cc(987): [client X.X.X.X] Not rewriting non-GET 2 of http://example.com/param1/param2/"

Tags: php, apache, mod-pagespeed

I have google page speed installed on my server, which host multiple services (PHP). One of the service is to provide updated feed to webpages. Client (webpage on AJAX) request for the updated feed every few seconds, if there is nothing new empty response is given.

Everything works fine but my apache error logs I see this appearing every time the client requests for feed

```
net/instaweb/apache/instaweb_handler.cc(987): [client X.X.X.X] Not rewriting non-GET 2 of http://example.com/param1/param2/
```

I have other services running on the server requesting data on AJAX too, but I dont see this messages for any other service.

Any idea why this message appears and what does this mean?